# Get percentage progress of web services

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services

To initiliaze an intranet web site, it's necessary run a web service to obtain some info configuration. For this web service, I'd like show a progress bar.

In this simple way

```
$.ajax({
    url: "app.asmx/init",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    xhrFields: {
    onprogress: function (e) {        
        if (e.lengthComputable) {
            console.log(e.loaded, e.total);
        }
     }
});
```

I get the `e.total` and `e.loaded` when the call to the web service is ended.

In this article ([not real percentage progress](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8b7513/jquery-progress-bar-in-Asp-Net/)), is explaned a way to obtain a fake progress bar: not real percentage progress because is used a `setInterval`.

How can I get a real percentage progress? How can I get a server progress?

Answer (score -1):

Use jQuery methods ***[.ajaxStart()](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/)*** and ***[.ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/)***.

Comment: I can't understand how .ajaxStart() and .ajaxComplete() can resolve my request: .ajaxStart() is 0%, .ajaxComplete() is 100%..but How I get the progress from 1% to 99%?

Comment: If you want to show the percentage from 1 to 100. Use **complete** method in jquery Ajax for each service request.

Comment: But the service request is unique: only app.asmx/init. Do you have a link for this approach?

Comment: So you want to call the request only once and still update the progress continuously?

Comment: The important is resolve my question. If I have to use more service request I will do it, but I can't figure out  how implement it. I'd like a link, if is possible, with more info about this solution